# Why does it say I don't have a rect

Tags: python, attributes, pygame, sprite

I have put in the code `self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)`. There is an `AttributeError: type object 'MobRow1' has no attribute 'rect'`. Why does this error keep popping up when I have put the `rect` in.

I have tried `self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)` This still doesn't work.

```
        class MobRow1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self, x, y):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.image.load(badguy_file).convert_alpha()
                self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)
                self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

            def update(self):
                self.rect.y += self.speedy
                self.rect.x += self.speedx
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: There must be another piece of code missing here. Is your function `update` called anywhere in your script ?

Comment: @ValBerthe it isn't called anywhere. Would you like me to show you all of the code?

Comment: @MaxCOSSETTO please add the error traceback first

Comment: @ValBerthe 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maxco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\codingandcaring github\Basketball 2.2.3.py", line 143, in <module>
    MobRow1.update(screen_rect)
  File "C:\Users\maxco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\codingandcaring github\Basketball 2.2.3.py", line 140, in update
    self.rect.y += self.speedy
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: Seems like in Basketball 2.2.3.py you're calling `update` without instanciating your object. Did you create a `MobRow1()`object first ?

Comment: @ValBerthe by object, do you mean sprite? Because I have made other sprites before this one, but no objects named `MobRow1()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177997/discussion-between-val-berthe-and-max-cossetto).

Answer (score 2):

You call `MobRow1.update(screen_rect)`, which will result in `self` being `screen_rect`.

So when `self.rect.y += self.speedy` is called, it will fail with an `AttributeError` because `self`, which is `screen_rect`, which is a `Rect` instance, does not have a `rect` attribute.

---

What you should do, is calling `update` *on an instance* of `MobRow1`, not on the `MobRow1` class itself. Also, if you do this, you either have to add another parameter to its `update` function or remove the `screen_rect` argument from the function call.

Comment: Can you please give an example and where would I put the code (eg. Main, Sprite etc.)

Comment: Because the suggested code isn't working for me currently.

Comment: @MaxCOSSETTO I can't give you an example because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, what `MobRow1` actually represents and how it should work in your game. Is there only ever one `MobRow1`? Is it always there? Then you should probably create it before your main loop, something like `mob = MobRow1(x, y)` and then call `mob.update()`